# Printing with excel and java or others

Tags: java, excel, printing, desktop-application

at the moment I am using `Desktop.print()` to print excel sheets. This looks quite stupid when you want to print one file 10 times. Excel opens up, prints, shutsdown and that 10 times.

I don't care about multiplatform stuff, so a call the `exec(excel.exe print-this 10-times);` would be perfectly okay.

How can this be done? Maybe displaying the excel print dialog?

Comment: If you are capable of converting the file to the google datasheet format without loss of information relevant to you, it might allow you to then use Google APIs which might have a much more friendly support for printing. This is just an idea though, but I don't know if it will be worth the hassle.

Answer (score -1):

Try a simple macro like this one, just make sure you change the parameters to what you want it as though!

sub printThis()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate         '// Activate the sheet you want to print
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup        '// Change the page setup parameters
    .Orientation = xlLandscape    '// xlLandscape or xlPortrait
    .Draft = False                '// If true then any graphics aren't printed
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4        '// Paper size
    .FitToPagesWide = 2           '// How wide you want it to be
    .FitToPagesTall = 1           '// How tall you want it to be
End With

'// Now print the selected page however many times you like!
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=10, Collate:=True

End sub

Here's an old reference to it on the MSDN library if you want to see all of the different parameters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174261(v=office.11).aspx